# FFMPEG-PHP Windows "Can't open movie file"

Tags: ffmpeg, xampp

ffmpeg extension is loaded as it is shown at phpinfo(), my file and script are at the same location, but I'm still getting this error.

```
Warning: Can't open movie file Untitled.avi in C:\xampp\htdocs\skelbiu\fetch.php  on line 4

Fatal error: Call to a member function getDuration() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\skelbiu\fetch.php on line 5
```

My script:

```
extension_loaded('ffmpeg') or die('Error in loading ffmpeg');

$ffmpegInstance = new ffmpeg_movie('Untitled.avi');
echo "getDuration: " . $ffmpegInstance->getDuration() .
"getFrameCount: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameCount() .
"getFrameRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameRate() .
"getFilename: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFilename() .
"getComment: " . $ffmpegInstance->getComment() .
"getTitle: " . $ffmpegInstance->getTitle() .
"getAuthor: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAuthor() .
"getCopyright: " . $ffmpegInstance->getCopyright() .
"getArtist: " . $ffmpegInstance->getArtist() .
"getGenre: " . $ffmpegInstance->getGenre() .
"getTrackNumber: " . $ffmpegInstance->getTrackNumber() .
"getYear: " . $ffmpegInstance->getYear() .
"getFrameHeight: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameHeight() .
"getFrameWidth: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameWidth() .
"getPixelFormat: " . $ffmpegInstance->getPixelFormat() .
"getBitRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getBitRate() .
"getVideoBitRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getVideoBitRate() .
"getAudioBitRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioBitRate() .
"getAudioSampleRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioSampleRate() .
"getVideoCodec: " . $ffmpegInstance->getVideoCodec() .
"getAudioCodec: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioCodec() .
"getAudioChannels: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioChannels() .
"hasAudio: " . $ffmpegInstance->hasAudio();
```

I'm using php 5.2.9 (XAMPP 1.7.1), Windows 7.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path to the movie has to be the full path. It doesn't matter where your script resides. Because you are using Win 7 and XAMPP, your path would be for example

```
$ffmpegInstance = new ffmpeg_movie('C:/xampp/htdocs/yourfolder/Untitled.avi');
```

I hope that this resolves your problem

Comment: Yeah, thanks, i had already solved my problem, but maybe this will be useful for someone else!